# Creating a secure login in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a secure login that will require a username and password. I am struggling with this and can not figure out the problem. When I try to access my login page I receive an error for <%= form_tag login_url do %> in the login page. If anyone can help me make this work, you will be my hero.

Schema for table that holds username and password

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "password_confirmation"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Controller from the table that holds username and password

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

The login page (which I can not get to work)

```
<h2>The Maintenance Functions are restricted to authorized users. Please login below</h2>
<%= form_tag login_url do %>
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag "login" %>
<% end %>
```

The controller for the login page

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController 
  def new  
  end

  def create 
    user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])

    if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to secertin_secertout_path :notice => "Logged in successfully"
    else
      flash.alert = "Invalid userid/password combination"
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def destroy 
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url_path :notice => "Logged Out" 
  end
end
```

Comment: The most simple thing you can do is use Devise: https://rubygems.org/gems/devise

Comment: It does what you are trying to do with less than 10 lines of code

Comment: okay I have installed it still running into the same error

Comment: If you use devise this code is no longer needed. Look at the devise documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best using [`Devise`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise) (or maybe [`Authlogic`](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic))

Reason being it's sometimes better to outsource something as important as `user authentication`. Why? Several reasons:

> 1. it's a vital part of your app
> 2. it needs to adapt with changes in HTTP security
> 3. it needs to work with other dependencies

If you roll your own authentication (which isn't that difficult), your major issue is you won't have the extensibility or reliability that one of these solutions provides. I would *highly* recommend using `devise` - it's doing exactly what you need anyway

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `password` and `password_confirmation` columns from your table and your code should work. `has_secure_password` gives you the virtual attributes `password` and `password_confirmation` but it stores a hashed version of the password in your table in the `password_digest` column. Not storing the plain text version of the password in the database is part of what makes `has_secure_password` secure.